# How to use JavaScript function in Apache velocity?

Tags: javascript, apache-velocity

I have a pre-built JavaScript function that I want to call in velocity template. I am not very well aware with the velocity and its syntax. I want to use JavaScript function of external script inside my current velocity template.

I've already added this script to include external JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ordertracking.js"></script>

#macro (drawRow)
    
#end

<table id="table-imac-tickets" class="table table-sm table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>  
        #foreach( $r in $ticketlist )  
            <tr>
                <td>
                  // here I want to use functionality of already built JS function that is written inside ordertracking.js file.
                    console.log($!{r.getSolrItem()})
                    #drawRow()
                </td>
            </tr>
        #end
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense to run JavaScript in the middle of a Velocity template.